# Android Google fit recording API not working

Tags: android, google-fit

I wanted to integrate google fit recording API from my application. And then i want to read the data using history API. From my phone i have uninstalled the google fit application so that i can make sure that the recording api integration is working perfect.

Please find the code below which i have done. When retrieving the data using History API, i am getting the buckets for those walks which i done but the data point is coming empty. Can anyone help me.

```
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                        new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                Log.i(GOOGLE_FIT_TAG, "Connected!");
                                subscribe();
                                bus.post(new GoogleFitConnectEvent());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                String errorMessage = "Connection lost. ";
                                if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                    errorMessage += "Cause: Network Lost.";
                                    Log.i(GOOGLE_FIT_TAG, errorMessage);
                                } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    errorMessage = "Reason: Service Disconnected";
                                    Log.i(GOOGLE_FIT_TAG, errorMessage);
                                }

                                bus.post(new GoogleFitConnectionErrorEvent(errorMessage));
                            }
                        }
                )
                .build();

public void subscribe() {
        Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(client, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {

                        } else {
                            Log.i(GOOGLE_FIT_TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
//Read data from History API:

Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(client, buildQuery(startTime, endTime))
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
                        Set<Workout> parsedWorkouts = parseWorkoutsFromFitnessData(dataReadResult);
                    }
                }, Constants.GOOGLE_FIT_TIMEOUT, Constants.GOOGLE_FIT_TIMEOUT_TIMEUNIT);


 private DataReadRequest buildQuery(long startTime, long endTime) {
        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()

                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                             .bucketByActivitySegment(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .enableServerQueries()
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        return readRequest;
    }

private Set<Workout> parseWorkoutsFromFitnessData(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
        List<Workout> workouts = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {

            for (DataSet dataSet : bucket.getDataSets()) {

                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {

                    for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                        Log.i(GOOGLE_FIT_TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + dp.getValue(field) + " ");
                    }

                        if (bucket.getActivity().equals(FitnessActivities.RUNNING) || bucket.getActivity().equals(FitnessActivities.WALKING)) {
                            long duration = dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MINUTES) - dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MINUTES);

                        }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: try using TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA in your subscribe method

Comment: Hi, after using TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA it was working for me. But from 2 months before it stopped working with this also.  so currently in my app i am subscribing TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA and reading TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA. Then i tried subscribing TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT and reading TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT datatype. Which is working on samsung s6 but not on samsung s3. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: if ` TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA ` worked then please put it as answer. Then ask a new question regarding the current issue